# How to acces class variables outside class in python

Tags: python, class, variables, scope

I am new to python and this is my first program in python i want to know how to access class variables outside class.I have a code which throws some error

```
from xxxxxxx import Products

class AccessKey(object):
    def key(self):
        self.products = Products(
           api_key = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
           api_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        )

class Data(AccessKey):
    def Print(self):
        products.products_field( "search", "Samsung Galaxy" )
        results = products.get_products()
        print "Results of query:\n", results

data = Data()
data.Print()
```

The above program throws following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "framework.py", line 10, in <module>
    class Data(AccessKey):
  File "framework.py", line 13, in Data
    results = products.get_products()
NameError: name 'products' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to call the products field as **self.products.** (etc)

It looks like you don't necessarily instantiate "products" before you call it. If you want to make sure it's instantiated, then you need to have products be set in the constructor of the parent class (AccessKey)

A simplified example would be:

```
class A (object):
    def __init__ (self):
        self.x = 1

class B (A):
    def get (self):
        return self.x

b = B ()
print (b.get ())
```

Basically, you would have to add the following constructor to your first class

```
class AccessKey(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.products = Products (X, Y) # or whatever you want to initialize it to
    # the rest of your code below
```

Or, you can be even better and create a set_product function:

```
# inside of the parent class
    def set_product (self, X, Y):
        try:
            self.products.product_field (X, Y)
        except NameError:
            self.products = Product (X, Y)
```

Answer (score 0):

the Class `Data` inherits from `AccessKey`. So the class attribute `products` is available to `Data`, however, you need to access it through

`self.products.products_field(...)` instead of `products.products_field(...)`.
similarly, it should be `results = self.products.get_products()`

But note that, the instance attribute products is only set when the method `key` is called, so you will get `NameError` until the `key` method is called, i.e.

```
data = Data()
data.key()
data.Print()
```

Also, in python getters and setters are discouraged, and a lot of stress is placed on code formatting guidelines. In your code the class methods *should* be lower case, but because `print` would shadow a reserverd word, something like `print_` would be preferable.